# How to stop a bash script from an infinite loop?

Tags: node.js, git, bash, githooks

I have this bash script in my project directory named as shrinkwrap.sh:

```
update_package_json_changed_files() {
  echo "> changed files"

  git diff --cached --name-only | grep -x package.json
}

update_shrinkwrap_and_at_to_git_index() {
  echo "> Updating npm-shrinkwrap.json and adding to current commit."

  npm shrinkwrap
  git add npm-shrinkwrap.json 
}

if get_package_json_changed_files; then
  update_shrinkwrap_and_at_to_git_index
fi
```

and I am running this script in package.json as the following:

```
"scripts": {
  "shrinkwrap": "bin/shrinkwrap.sh"
}
```

and I installed npm pre-commit in order to execute the script as the following:

```
"pre-commit": ["shrinkwrap"]
```

when I try to commit, the script goes into an infinte loop. It keeps running, and nothing can stop it. I tried command + C, control + Z. Nothing worked. Did anyone run into this issue before ? why is that happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that it is triggered on file change, and proceed to change at least one file, which in turns triggers it (on file change), which makes it change a file, which... and so on.

A usual way to break that is to generate a flag file (touch /tmp/in_progress), and to call `update_shrinkwrap_and_at_to_git_index()` only if that file does *not* exist.
If it exists, delete it (but don't do anything else)

So:

- `update_shrinkwrap_and_at_to_git_index()` a `touch /tmp/in_progress` and
- before `if get_package_json_changed_files;` add a `if [ -e /tmp/in_progress ]; then rm /tmp/in_progress; exit 0; fi`

---

The [OP Max Doung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5860075/max-doung) comments:

> I added `sudo` to in front of `npm shrinkwarp`, and it did stop the loop.when I take it out, loop starts again. Wondering why?

That suggests the hook is triggered by a user-local settings (one in `~/.gitconfig` for instance)

Executing the command with a different account (here `root`, through `sudo`) would avoid using said global user account-specific setting.

Comment: I added sudo to in front of npm shrinkwarp, and it did stop the loop.when I take it out, loop starts again. Wondering why?

Comment: @MaxDoung I have edited the answer to respond to your comment.

Comment: I have two more questions please. Where do I replace (touch /tmp/in_progress). Also, can you explain a little bit about why this infinite loop is happening please? I have little experience with this; thanks a lot.

Comment: @MaxDoung I don't have much beside the first part of the answer which illustrates how the infinite loop operates. If adding `sudo` avoids the infinite loop, that means your local config must include something. Can you edit your question with the content of `git config -l`, executed within your repo folder.

Comment: @MaxDoung Where do I replace (touch /tmp/in_progress): you add that line in the `update_shrinkwrap_and_at_to_git_index()` function: that will leave a marker signaling that `update_shrinkwrap_and_at_to_git_index()` was executed.

Comment: @MaxDoung you need a space between `progress` and `]`.